# Binary only TextArea in javafx

Tags: javafx-8, custom-controls

I have a simple [Binary to ASCII Converter](https://github.com/iamaamir/stribin) and i want to Limit the Binary TextArea to accept only 0 and 1. any idea how can i do this in javafx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to accept or reject changes:

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
final Pattern binary = Pattern.compile("^[01]*$");
final Predicate<String> tester = binary.asPredicate();
ta.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    if (!tester.test(change.getControlNewText())) {
        return null;
    }
    return change;
}));
```

Comment: Note that this only allows a single line. If you want to allow multiple lines you would have to modify the regular expression (Something like `final Pattern binary = Pattern.compile("\\A[01\\n]*\\Z");` should work).

Comment: yup but i think since the TextArea is going to hold only 01 `[01]+` may work fine

Comment: That would mean the user can't clear the TextArea, though. If that's fine then `[01]+` is good, but usually it is desirable to allow a completely empty input.

Comment: agreed going with `"\\A[01\\n]*\\Z"`